# Centering a div on a scrolled page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code:

```
<div id="overlay" style="
    display: none;
    border: solid #aa0 10px;
    width: 75vh;
    height: 80vh;
    z-index: 650;
    position: absolute;
    left:50%; top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)"
>
```

It is hidden at first, but if I click on specific screen elements I have some jquery code that displays it with `show()`.

This centers perfectly if the page is not scrolled, however, if the page is scrolled when the user clicks on one of the screen elements, the overlay will appear centered as if the page was not scrolled. (i.e. it will be centered at the top of the page even if it is out of view).

How can I fix this so that it centers in the viewport no matter where the page is scrolled to?

Comment: Sheesh, I tried changing it to fixed about half an hour ago and it didn't display at all. I must have made a mistake when I did it the first time. Thank you!

Comment: can you make fiddle for this?

Comment: It works now that I changed it to fixed.

Comment: please provide snippet or fiddle..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need change position from **absolute** to **fixed**

```
<div id="overlay" style="
    display: none;
    border: solid #aa0 10px;
    width: 75vh;
    height: 80vh;
    z-index: 650;
    position: fixed;
    left:50%; top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)"
>
```

Comment: Thanks. I did try using fixed about half an hour ago and it wasn't working. It is working now. I must have made a mistake the first time. :)